# Can wp_strip_all_tags be used as a substitute for esc_url, esc_attr & esc_html?

Tags: escaping

`esc_url, esc_attr & esc_html` are used to escape content that is untrusted so that potentially malicious code isn't executed. Can `wp_strip_all_tags` be used as an alternative? If not, why?

Comment: No, escaping HTML output is not same as stripping/removing/sanitizing HTML from output. Consider e.g. if you need to display HTML code in your blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. They do different things. `wp_strip_all_tags()` strips HTML tags from a given string, but that's not the only reason you escape things. `esc_attr()`, for example, ensures that `"` characters are escaped so that a value doesn't break HTML attributes.

For example, if I have a variable whose value is the string `my-"class`, and I want to put it into an HTML attribute:

```
$my_class = 'my-"class';
echo '<div class="' . $my_class . '"></div>';
```

The resulting HTML will be:

```
<div class="my-"class"></div>
```

Which is invalid HTML, because the `"` in my value has closed the HTML attribute. `wp_strip_all_tags()` will not help you here.

Comment: Thanks. When should `wp_strip_all_tags()` be used?

Comment: When you want to strip tags from a string? I don't know really. I've never needed to use it. It might make more sense using it for sanitisation, so that tags are removed from a value on saving it, rather than on display, since this would communicate to the user that HTML tags are not allowed, while escaping just causes them to be displayed as plain text.